# Is there any way to sum the recurrence $R_n = \frac{(R_{n-1})^2(R_{n-2})}{(\sqrt{R_{n-1}}+ \sqrt{R_{n-2}})^2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

> Is there any way to sum this recurrence relation?
> $$R_n = \frac{(R_{n-1})^2(R_{n-2})}{\left(\sqrt{R_{n-1}}+ \sqrt{R_{n-2}}\right)^2}$$

I was thinking there could be some way to telescope this. There were some ways to split the fraction but all those ways involve sums, and not differences, meaning they can't be telescoped that way.

Do you know some way to sum this or other similar recurrences?

Comment: To sum the recurrence? What does that even mean?

Comment: As in the sum up to n terms. If the nth term is found, the sum up to n terms can be found(Sn - Sn-1 = Rn), so really the aim is to find Rn as a function of n

Comment: There does not seem to be a hope for a closed formula. Why do you think you need it, really?